# How can I delete these characters in a csv file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, formatting

I have a code that generates a table and prints it as a csv file but when I run it, it also displays certain characters like quotation marks and parenthesis.

I currently don't have pandas, so if there's a solution that does not include it, I would greatly appreciate it. I know it should be something "simple" as all it is, is a formatting issue. Below is the piece of code that prints the table and also my current and desire results

Code:

```
def PrintAsCsv(table):
    for r in table:
        print((r[0], r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8]))
```

Current results in the header of the table:

('Ssid'  'Vlan'  'Connected Time' 'Rssi' 'Date' 'Wap Name' 'Device Name')

Desired results in the header of the table:

Ssid Vlan Connected Time Rssi Date Wap Name Device Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your fields contain spaces, you'll want to have a different separator, e.g. a comma (default for csv):

```
def PrintAsCsv(table):
    for r in table:
        print(','.join((r[0], r[1], r[3], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8])))
```

Output:

```
Ssid,Vlan,Connected Time,Rssi,Date,Wap Name,Device Name
```